# How to validate that client is already inputing the photo/files type in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, mern

i try to make a code that if the user not inputing the photo they will get the message "you're not yet inputing the photo" i was using this code to do that

```
    const isEmpty = (value) =>
  value === undefined ||
  value === null ||
  (typeof value === "object" && Object.keys(value).length === 0) ||
  (typeof value === "string" && value.trim().length === 0);

module.exports = isEmpty;
```

and calling them by :

```
    const Validator = require("validator");
const isEmpty = require("./is-empty");

module.exports = validateCreatePost = (data) => {
  let errors = {};

  data.title = !isEmpty(data.title) ? data.title : "";
  data.fieldContent = !isEmpty(data.fieldContent) ? data.fieldContent : "";
  data.imageContent = !isEmpty(data.imageContent) ? data.imageContent : "";
  data.genreContent = !isEmpty(data.genreContent) ? data.genreContent : "";

  if (!Validator.isLength(data.title, { min: 5, max: 256 })) {
    errors.title = "Title must be between 5 and 256 characters";
  }
  if (Validator.isEmpty(data.title)) {
    errors.title = "Title field is required";
  }
  if (!Validator.isLength(data.fieldContent, { min: 100 })) {
    errors.fieldContent = "Body field need atleast 100 characters";
  }
  if (Validator.isEmpty(data.fieldContent)) {
    errors.fieldContent = "Body field is required";
  }
  if (Validator.isEmpty(data.imageContent)) {
    errors.imageContent = "Image field is required";
  }
  if (Validator.isEmpty(data.genreContent)) {
    errors.genreContent = "Genre is required";
  }
  return {
    errors,
    isValid: isEmpty(errors),
  };
};
```

but whenever i try to input the photo from Postman they always give me this message

[Postman Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4JfY.png)

i'm stuck to solve this problem.